# How to write Octave code on LaTeX?

Tags: listings, code, octave

Here is an exemple of code I would like to write:

```
clear all; close all; clc;

X = Y = 0:0.1:1;

for i=1:length(X)
  for j=1:length(Y)
    Z(i, j) = X(i) + Y(j);
  endfor
endfor

mesh(Y, X, Z)
```

The problem is that list that lstlisting does not take colors, and I would like my code to appear exacly as it appears on Octave (almost the same environnement as Matlab). How could I do that ?

Comment: Have you tried using `lstlisting` (lot of examples around) telling it it is Matlab code? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75116/what-can-i-use-to-typeset-matlab-code-in-my-document could be helpful

Comment: Without a screenshot of what you expect it is hard to tell, but this might help as well: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430527/how-to-display-colors-of-octave-code-in-latex-with-listings

Comment: for a strange reason, I couldn't add a picture to this post... Thanks for the links !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using `minted` and *not* `lstlisting` as the code is easier to copy from the PDF and run. Copying code from `lstlisting` produces **many** errors that must be fixed before the code can run. Minted has several styles, so you can chose the one you like the most for highlighting. Overleaf has a [Reference guide](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Code_Highlighting_with_minted#Reference_guide) of all the minted styles. Also, minted supports the `octave` language.

[image]

Here the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usemintedstyle{manni} 
\definecolor{LightGray}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}[!htb]

\begin{minted}[
bgcolor=LightGray,
breaklines,
breaksymbolleft={},
breakindent={15pt}
]{octave}
clear all; close all; clc;

X = Y = 0:0.1:1;

for i=1:length(X)
  for j=1:length(Y)
    Z(i, j) = X(i) + Y(j);
  endfor
endfor

mesh(Y, X, Z)
\end{minted}

% \inputminted[%
% firstline=, 
% lastline=,
% bgcolor=LightGray,
% breaklines,
% breaksymbolleft={},
% breakindent={15pt}
% ]{octave}{Folder/file}

\caption{Code}
\label{listing:1}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

Here is the code copied from the `lstlisting` environment:

```
c l e a r a l l ; c l o s e a l l ; c l c ;
X = Y = 0 : 0 . 1 : 1 ;
for i =1: length (X)
for j =1: length (Y)
Z( i , j ) = X( i ) + Y( j ) ;
endfor
endfor
mesh(Y, X, Z)
```

Here is the code copied from `minted` environment:

```
clear all; close all; clc;
X = Y = 0:0.1:1;
for i=1:length(X)
for j=1:length(Y)
Z(i, j) = X(i) + Y(j);
endfor
endfor
mesh(Y, X, Z)
```

There are also other problems with `lstlisting` that does not show in this example:

1. all minus signs (-) turns into hyphens (slightly longer) and must be replaced
2. all multiplication signs (*) stop working for some reason and must be replaced

I once had to copy and run code from the `lstlisting` environment (I only had a PDF) and had fix over 100 mistakes before I could run the code. Almost all of these mistakes could have been avoided using `minted` instead of `lstlisting`.

Comment: Oh, thanks ! I regret I already used lstlisting everywhere... would you know how to replace all the \lstinputlisting{file.m} by minted without deleting what @I'm the 1 put in the header ? It would take me ages to undo the lst style

Comment: If you use Overleaf you can use the replace function. Just click `Ctrl+F` and a little search window pops up. In the "search for" field write `\lstinputlisting` and in the "replace with" field write `\inputminted`. And then just click "replace" (replaces 1 at each click) or "all".

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot ! Last question: how do I put some special words in special colors (e.g. "+", "-", "*", "/" in red and "function", "endfunction" in blue) ?

Comment: I just saw your link, it's ok ! Thanks again